# Member 'Enemy_health.enemiesKilled' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

probably a problem of static usage, i searched for the solution but didn't find it, i have this as parameter "private Enemy_health killcount ;"
and this in start function  "killcount =  GetComponent<Enemy_health>() ;"

also "public static float enemiesKilled ;" in enemy_health script

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
{
    if (!alrdySpawned)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Player 1")
        {
            killcount.enemiesKilled = 0 ;
            startTimer = true ;
            StartCorou = true ;
            alrdySpawned = true ;
            if(StartCorou)
            {
                StartCoroutine(SpawnMonsters()) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have defined `enemiesKilled` as a static property, did you really want to do that?

Comment: yes i did mean it like that otherwise whenever an enemy dies it just counts and stops at 1

Answer (score 0):

Because the instance name does not match the first object name, which is usually written this way. This code only works for the primary object.

I suggest you to replace the part of code with tag comparison to fix this problem.

```
if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
```

If you are not already familiar with it, go to the guide to using tags in Unity:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html